# Cloth refuses to respond to collisions

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14LJy_ZWYfDyOPy08cCFAWvnMrFINrX7g/view?usp=sharing

I have a cloth and a cube (with very minor bevels) but collision doesn't work between them.
I've checked the face orientation and it's fine.

Not sure what's wrong, as every bit of physics works fine except for collisions.

Comment: You have not give Collision to the cube, only Rigid Body, so it will fall but won't interact with the cloth.

Comment: @moonboots what do you mean? Do I need to add the collision modifier?

Comment: Yes or in the Physics panel > Collision. It seems also doable with Soft Body: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m1RcagR9sw

Comment: @moonboots ahh thanks!